# How to check if you have permission to run a exe file

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, exe

C# .net Framework 4.0
Is there a simple way to check if you have the rights to run a file?

Before i do this:

```
//e.g. Press a button
....
string exePath = "D:\something\something.exe";
Process.Start(exePath);
```

i would like to check if the user has the rights to run that file?
When i'm making the function call Process.Start, windows popsup with a messagebox and says that i'm not authorized to run this application and this application is "D:\something\something.dat" and NOT .exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to check if you have permission to run a exe file?

EAFP: *It is Easier to Ask Forgiveness than it is to get Permission*.

So, you can surround your code with try/catch block:

```
try {
    Process.Start(path);
} catch (Win32Exception ex) {
    // ...
}
```

and you can use [`Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception.nativeerrorcode.aspx) to access the numeric representation of the error code associated with this exception.

For more information about the error codes, check out [Win32 System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Try surrounding `Proccess.Start` with `try catch`:

```
//e.g. Press a button
....
    string exePath = "D:\something\something.exe";
    try
    {
        Process.Start(exePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // No permissions or file not found?
    }
```

that'll do the job.

Comment: Trapping the specific exception(s) would be better.

Comment: Another problem is that when i do this: Process.Start(exePath)
A messageBox appears and says that i don't have the rights to something..

The reason I ask is because I need to display a menu with the files the user can open. It would be nice to exclude the files the user doesn't have permissions to open.